# div's innerhtml content replacing the content of a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div that its content is pulled from innerhtml as shown

```
var users = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    users += '<strong>' + json[i].name + '</strong><br/>';
                }
                users_container.innerHTML = users;
            }
```

this is the div that the innerhtml replaces its content. The content of the div only displays for some seconds and disappears.

```
<div id="users-container" class="inner-container">
    <h3>Active users</h3>
    </div>
```

Please how can I retain the content of the div as a header while the innerhtml contents is displayed as well. Kindly assist!

Comment: Please tag your questions with the appropriate tags - this is clearly a javascript issue and doesn't even use CSS3 anywhere.

Comment: okay thanks. we learn everyday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a specific `div` for the `users` content and keep the original content of your `div`.

**JavaScript:**

```
var users_div = document.getElementById("users_div");
var users = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    users += '<strong>' + json[i].name + '</strong><br/>';
                }
                users_div.innerHTML = users;
            }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="users-container" class="inner-container">
    <h3>Active users</h3>
    <div id="users_div">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this keeps multiplying the content of the inerhtml. For eg I now several users repeating endlessly

Comment: In that case you can an inner div specific to the users content.

Answer (score 1):

html

```
 <div id="users-container" class="inner-container">
    <h3>Active users</h3>
    <div id="usersList"></div>
 </div>
```

script

```
var users = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    users += '<strong>' + json[i].name + '</strong><br/>';
                }
                usersList.innerHTML = users;
            }
```

Comment: I want it in the same div in other not affect already existing page layout

Comment: It will not affect the page layout as it is in the same div just as your H3 is, but this way you'll get to preserve the header describing what those names are instead of deleting it as soon as the list of active users is populated, meaning your current code is contrary to my suggestion destroying your existing layout

Comment: adding it scatters my page layout

Comment: Quite the contrary- it doesn't! It is you who are destroying your page layout grid by deleting the ACTIVE USERS header with your users list. Adding the a do-nothing container such as a DIV list container doesn't affect the existing layout design, at all.